# First Hands-on PCB

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I want to print a board from open-source hardware [found here](https://github.com/cutiepi-io/cutiepi-board).  I don't know how to go about filling in the specifications on the website. It may look so straightforward and direct, but I don't have any electronics background so please try to use sugar-coated easy words on explanation. I want to print it on PCBway, and I have an account there already.

Comment: What specifications are you referring to?

Comment: In the process of making the order, there are the board specifications that you have to fill, layers, FR4_TG, Min hole size. Those kind of specifications.

Comment: Only a suggestion, if you're willing to try another PCB vendor: OSHPark.com.  They have tutorials on using the various design tools (your example seems to be in OrCad) and sensible defaults. (I do not work for them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hardly an expert, but I am curious...

For a quote, go with the defaults unless you know your board is different.

Traditionally units are mils (1/1000) of an inch. Millimeter is more modern. Both are still used.

4 layers is an educated guess looking at the .art files.

FR4, 1.6mm thick is fairly standard. Thinner for really small boards to save weight. Thicker for large boards or when mechanical support is necessary.

The drill file lists 10 (mils) as the smallest drill, This is 0.254mm.

The trace widths should be in the .art files somewhere, but I can't read them.

1 oz copper unless it is a power board.

Tin/Lead is usually easier to work with, but is prohibited in some areas (European Union).

Send all the files to the vendor and see how much they will help you.

[image]